# Swift Ternary Operator function call?

Tags: swift, if-statement, ternary

I want to start using the Swift ternary operator so that I don't set values but I fire different functions.

```
if position.x < kWidth / 2 ? fireLeft() : fireRight()
```

It does not work, and I am actually quite by that. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: What's the signature of `fireLeft()` / `fireRight()`?

Answer (score 6):

The `if` keyword is not needed in the ternary operator.

Comment: @CeceXX: Re your edit: `if` is a keyword, not a constructor.

Comment: Thanks I just realised it myself a couple of seconds too late! I blame the wine from yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

You should not write `if` keyword while using ternary operator.

Your statement would be:

```
position.x < kWidth/2 ? fireLeft() : fireRight()
```

The `?` operator reads as if the statement before `?` returns boolean `TRUE`, then call the `fireLeft()` function else call `fireRight()` function.

Answer (score 0):

use : `(condition) ? (option 1) : (option 2)`
it works like this :

```
if (condition = true) {
(option 1)
}else {
(option 2)
}
```